# Conditions in querysets

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Dashboards table and a table that defines the "editor" permission as follows:

```
Dashboard    
=========  
id     Name         Owner   
--     ----         -----    
1     Dashboard1     555

DashboardUsers
==============
id  dashboard_id    user_id     editor
--  -----------     -------      -------
1       1            222          true
2       1            333          true
```

Lets say that Owner that exists in Dashboard table is also an editor but this info does not exists in DashboardUsers table.
So i m trying to construct a queryset that checks editor rows (including the Owner ).
So i replace @userparamexample with 222 the queryset will correctly return a row. But if i replace the @userparamexample with 555 i will not get anyting.
How do i have to moderate the query to get if someone is an editor(owner).

```
models.Dashboard.filter(
    dashboarduser__user_id=@userparamexample,
    dashboarduser__editor=True
)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the owner 555 is actually an editor? Maybe this is the reason you're getting an empty qs

Comment: This is how I want my application to work